# Getting errors when switching screen to RootViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, screen

I'm hopeless at the moment, I need some help here.

So from the beginning:

I've made a view based app which I want to use as the main app. And I have build another app which is a navigation based one.

I combined the two projects into one, I dragged and dropped the navigation one in de first app I've made. I added the header file to the .m file of the view based one. So far so good. But when I add this code:

```
-(IBAction)search
{  
  RootViewController *search = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
  search.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
  [self presentModalViewController:search animated:YES];
}
```

Then I'll get two errors which is:

**Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RootViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Home.o**

**ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

So what I'm trying to do here is when I click on a button in the main app the screen needs to go to the main one from the other app.
I tried changing the RootViewController into UINavigationController and that worked, but it's not the fullscreen of course. I need to show the RootView Controller.

Can someone help me? Or if you need more info please let me know!
iPhone 4S, Mac OS X (10.7.3), XCODE

Comment: Combine the two projects into one by just adding the required class files into the new project.

Comment: Hi Kirby and Jason,
Thank you for the answer, but I already done this? See my screenshot: http://www.the-developers.nl/screenshot.png

So What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add RootViewController.m to the project that's complaining. The RootViewController.h by itself will not work.

Comment: Hi Kirby and Jason,
Thank you for the answer, but I already done this? See my screenshot: http://www.the-developers.nl/screenshot.png

So What to do?